# Secondary standby server log shipping backup job error

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am getting the following error while my log shipping job is trying to copy from the primary server:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn>sqllogship.exe -copy C83E29 23-5131-4767-A902-7E06A2572EA8 -server 831873-DB5

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Log Shipping Agent [Assembly Version = 11.0.0.0, File Version = 11.0.2100.60 ((SQL11_RTM).120210-19 17 )] Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

2016-11-30 04:24:19.53  ----- START OF TRANSACTION LOG COPY   ----- 
2016-11-30 04:24:19.61  Starting transaction log copy. Secondary ID: 'c83e2923-5 131-4767-a902-7e06a2572ea8' 
2016-11-30 04:24:19.61  Retrieving copy settings. Secondary ID: 'c83e2923-5131-4 767-a902-7e06a2572ea8' 
2016-11-30 04:24:19.61  Retrieved copy settings. Primary Server: '642165-DB4', P rimary Database: 'TestDB1', Backup Source Directory: '\\642165-DB4\Incoming', Ba ckup Destination Directory: '\\831873-DB5\Outgoing', Last Copied File: ''
2016-11-30 04:24:19.62  Copying log backup files. Primary Server: '642165-DB4', Primary Database: 'TestDB1', Backup Source Directory: '\\642165-DB4\Incoming', B ackup Destination Directory: '\\831873-DB5\Outgoing' 
2016-11-30 04:24:19.65  *** Error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (mscorlib) *** 
2016-11-30 04:24:19.67  ----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG COPY     -----

Exit Status: 1 (Error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear the credential used for the copy job cannot be validated by the server that stores the T-Log backups or copied T-Log backups.

What account have you configured for log shipping copy job?

To access the destination disk, the admin there has to create an NT user and grant permissions. Ask for the help of your Windows administrator.

Verify that the account in use by SQL Server Agent has a login at the secondary server with sufficient permissions.

Make sure a login is created at Windows level with proper access to destination server.